# How to get cell data from gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row

I am trying to fetch data from certain GridView row when I click link in that row...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" AllowPaging="True">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="nazivTeme" HeaderText="nazivTeme" 
                        SortExpression="nazivTeme" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="datum" HeaderText="datum" SortExpression="datum" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkView" commandname="view"
                            OnClick="lnkView_Click">Komentiraj</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

I would like to get data from the row where I click the LinkButton (only first cell).
I hope you understand what I want :)

Comment: thanks alot. I'm looking into this. I am not sure if this is what I'm looking for but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not subscribe to `Click` event of the button. Instead, subscribe to the `RowCommand` event of the grid view. Then, in the event handler, you can evaluate which command was received and which row was affected. Once you get the row, you can get its cell value by cell index or ID:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "view")
  {
     // Retrieve the row index
     int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

     // Retrieve the row by its index
     GridViewRow row = this.GridView1.Rows[index];

    // Get the 1st cell value from the row
    string cellValue = r.Cells[0].Text;
  }
```

}

Comment: I've written that method like this: protected void lnkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
       Label1.Text = name;} but i get error nullreference exception

Comment: You're close, but SelectedRow has nothing to do with that; you're clicking a button in a row, not selecting a row.

Comment: But can I access row data by clicking that button? If not I'll have to try something else :/

Comment: Sorry, I misled you; I was thinking of a different control. I updated the answer.

Comment: Found a solution :) Filburt's comment was helpful... using the OnSelectedIndexChanged method, and it works now

Comment: You should be going after the RowCommand event of your Grid View.